# How to render and filter a list of dictionnaries using JinjaTemplates

Tags: jinja2, fastapi

I'm new to Fast-API & Jinja2.

I'm looking for the right way to render and filter a list through Jinja2Template html page.

I developped this Fast-API :

```py
# Imports 
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request

# Environment
app = FastAPI()
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="static")

# Routes & endpoints
@app.get("/")
async def get_records(request : Request):
    my_list = [
        {"a": "foo", "b":"bar"},
        {"a": "foo1", "b":"bar1"},
        {"a": "foo2", "b":"bar2"},
    ]
    return templates.TemplateResponse("items.html", {"request" : request, "my_list" : mylist})

# Main thread
if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=42)
```

I also start writting my ./static/items.html

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block head %}
{{ super() }}
{% endblock %}

{% block page_content %}
<div>
  Hello team
</div>

# Here is where I want my list mylist to be render with the possibility filter 
{% endblock %}
```

As I said, I am pretty new to Fast-API and I did not find, on https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/templates/ the way to manage it.

Can you help me to find the way to do this ? I'm pretty sure I have to write a JS script.

Answer (score 0):

> Here is where I want my list mylist to be render with the possibility filter

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve, anyway here's my answer according to two possible interpretations. You don't necessarily have to use JavaScript either way.

You correctly passed along the list data as `context` parameter value of your `TemplateResponse` object (FastAPI uses Starlette under the hood, see [docs here](https://www.starlette.io/templates/)).
You now only need to reference it in your template by the specified key, namely `my_list`.

https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block head %}
{{ super() }}
{% endblock %}

{% block page_content %}
<div>
  {{ my_list }}
</div>
```

If you only want display certain items, i.e. *filter out* some of them, you could either do that in your view method using standard Python, for example using builtin `filter()` function (→ see [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=filter#filter)) or by using a Jinja filter in your template.

If you want to use **Jinja2 filters** to modify the passed data in your template you can leverage one of Jinja's many builtin filters described in [Jinjas documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#list-of-builtin-filters) or even implement your own filter function as a simple Python function as described in [Starlette](https://www.starlette.io/templates/) and [Jinja2 docs on creating custom filters](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/#custom-filters).

Comment: Hey! Thank a lot for your answer. I gonna try these 2 options. 
What I'm looking for is a way to render 500 items for exemples, and then to filter these items to get the items where the key "a" contains the value "foo" (as an example). 
I believe the function *.filter* has this functionnality :)

Comment: You're welcome! You can upvote or select my answer as as solution if it served your purpose.
In your case I'd go for Python's builtin `filter()`: you just need to pass it a function that returns `True` for every item you want to have in the resulting list: `filtered_items = filter(lambda x: x.get("a") == "foo", original_list)`.